# What are the products of the reaction between methanamine and nitrous acid?

Tags: organic-chemistry, amines

> What are the products of the reaction between methanamine and nitrous acid?

I'm finding this particular reaction *very* problematic. Here's why:

My teacher tells me that *methanamine*, when treated with *nitrous acid* (created by reacting sodium nitrite and hydrochloric acid) converts to an the unstable (at room temperature) intermediate: *methane diazonium chloride*, which decomposes in the (aqueous) solution to yield **methanol**, **hydrogen chloride** and **dinitrogen**.

A friend of mine (who happens to be a fairly trustworthy senior), tells me that the *actual* products are **methoxymethane** and **dinitrogen**, since methanamine is an *exception* and doesn't give the same kind of products the other primary aliphatic amines do (he read it up a long time ago, but doesn't remember *where*).

In hope of clearing up this mess, I resorted to my trusty copy of Organic Chemistry (Morrison and Boyd, 7th edition), according to which, the products of a reaction between a primary aliphatic amine and nitrous acid should be: **dinitrogen** and a **mixture of alcohols and alkenes**.

[image]

It doesn't mention anything about methanamine being an exception, and *"a mixture of alcohols and alkenes"* is a little ambiguous. Also I didn't discard this idea because *maybe* - through *some* method I don't even know - the methyl bits from the amines might couple and *somehow* result in an alkene. I wouldn't know since I'm relatively new to amine + nitrous acid reactions, so I won't take the risk.

I couldn't find any trust-worthy reference on this issue for this reaction. I need help resolving this ambiguity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both the teacher and the friend are partially right, but keep in mind that reaction products depend on reaction conditions, not just reactants.

According to [Chemical Mutagens Environmental Effects on Biological Systems](https://books.google.com/books?id=1RC4vDcQtXMC&pg=PA253&lpg=PA253&dq=%22nitrous%20acid%22%20methyl%20amine%20methanol%20methylnitrite&source=bl&ots=kK-lRaNQ9I&sig=GIBYgWwRQubmqSATXmHG1BGXbr8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjEr_el_8jPAhUEeCYKHS8uDjIQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=%22nitrous%20acid%22%20methyl%20amine%20methanol%20methylnitrite&f=false) (2012):

In the presence of Cl-,

1. $\ce{CH3+}$,  is formed.

2a. $\ce{CH3+ + H2O -> CH3OH +H+}$

2b. $\ce{CH3+ + NO2- -> CH3NO2}$ and $\ce{CH3+ + NO2- -> CH3ONO}$

2c. $\ce{CH3+ + Cl- -> CH3Cl}$

2d. $\ce{CH3+}$ reacts with methylamine to form dimethyl amine

3. Methanol formed above can react with $\ce{CH3+}$ to form dimethyl ether
4. Methanol can also react with nitrous acid to form methyl nitrite

The above book is relying upon Austin, A. T., [The Action of Nitrous Acid on Aliphatic Amines](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v188/n4756/abs/1881086a0.html) *Nature* 188, 1086-1088 (1960) as reference 472 to support the above information.

Austin explains that, under the reaction conditions:

0.5 mole methylamine hydrochloride
1.5 moles sodium nitrite
550 ml water
slowly acidified with 0.4 to 0.6 equivalents of 2N sulphuric acid
room temperature

products are as follows:

methanol: 6-25%
methyl nitrite: 45-35%
methyl chloride: 13%
nitromethane : 6%
methylnitrolic acid: 10-12%

Austin then states:

> The multiplicity of products formed in the above reaction is rationally explained if one assumes that the electron-deficient entity $\ce{CH3+}$  is formed - a suggestion originally put forth by Whitmore [reference 7] for this type of reaction.

While Austin discusses the possibility of dimethyl ether and dimethyl amine also forming, he does not indicate that they were observed experimentally.

Comment: Nearly all chemistry that is taught in undergrad etc. was performed decades ago.

Comment: I would need to see their kinetic or mechanistic data, but I am extremely suspicious of a methyl cation in aqueous solution. This seems extremely implausible. This isn't FVP, it's at 0 degrees C.

Comment: @Zhe I think this is the primary source http://www.jstor.org/stable/43418182?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents but I don't have full text access to that right now

Comment: I would've bought the carbocation for secondary or tertiary amines, but for methylamine, that's just a hard pill to swallow.

Comment: @Zhe "The unequivocal presence of
methyl chloride in the product gas when sodium
chloride is used in the solvent for methylamine
supports the suggestion of Austin [15] and others that
the organic portion of the amine may go through
a carbonium ion intermediate in the Van Slyke reaction." http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/j150569a025

Comment: @DavePhD I'm not sure why the Okkam razaor mechanism here isn't just SN2 reaction with chloride? Not sure if I'm looking at the same Austin paper (JChemSoc, 1961, 3593)? But that definitely suggests an intramolecular displacement of dinitrogen via the carbonyl group, i.e. not via carbocation. Also, that substrate would've been a primary amine, not methyl...

Comment: According to the terminology I learnt at uni, it should be a carb**e**nium ion *(lack* of a bond) not a carb**o**nium (an *additional* bond).

Comment: Unfortunately I can’t access the mechanism either. But to be perfectly honest, I see no reason why the reaction *must* happen under $\mathrm{S_N1}$ conditions. Until proven otherwise, I will assume a mixture of $\mathrm{S_N1}$ and $\mathrm{S_N2}$ because that seems most reasonable. (CC@Zhe; I approve of bringing Occam’s razor into the discussion!)

Comment: I added information from the original A.T. Austin reference that says the mechanism is via CH3+ , but I agree it isn't proof.  The reference is very good for answering the OP's question about what the actual products are, however.

Answer (score 9):

No chance to get alkenes from methanamine because there's no $\beta$-hydrogen for E2 elimination. And E1 elimination isn't going to work because you're not going to generate a methyl cation from the diazonium. The mixture of alcohols is probably because the alkyl cation *could* rearrange, but you're not creating the cation intermediate in this reaction.

The diazonium is a very good leaving group, so this complex is certainly going to be susceptible to S<sub>N</sub>2 reactions. The best and most available nucleophile you have in your mixture is water (the solvent), so you're going to get methanol.

Now, methanol could be a nucleophile that reacts with diazonium, but you're in aqueous solution. That means that the amount of water is going to dwarf any methanol that is produced. A negligible amount of the dimethyl ether will be produced.